# Generics issue in C#

Tags: c#, generics, data-structures

I'm trying to implement a Table, divided this up to 3 levels.

```
class Field -> 
      class Record (witch holds a collection of fields ) -> 
              class Table(witch holds a collection of Records)
```

now my question is not of the correct way to structure this implementation , although any pointers would be welcomed .

iv'e got a problem with implementing a generic field class

```
 public class Field<T>
 {
     T value; 
     Type _type; 
     string _header;
 }
```

i don't know what type T would be of so i need to define the class with  , 
now the problem that i'm facing is that the collection of **Field** in the Record class would most likely hold different types of **T**  **and that kinda defeats the all purpose**

```
public class Record
{
   List<Field<object>> fields ;        
}
```

so now i need to cast the T to object because T wont be of a specific type .

any idea's the work around this accept drooping the all generics idea and defining value as object , would be most appreciated.

plus any pointers about my implementation idea

my table consists of

```
    class Table  
    {   
          KeyValuePair<string,Type>[] columns ;
          KeyValuePair<string, Type> primary_key;
          string entitie_name ; 
          List<Reocrd> records ;
    }
    // the Record class could be created only from a table template just like a datarow
    public class Record
    {
          List<Field<object>> fields ;
          string primary_key ;// the name of the field witch i use to extract a value              
    }
```

10x in advance.

Comment: you appear to be re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: This cannot be done with generics alone. You will need to: a) burden the user of your class with the responsibility of asking for a specific type of data, or b) use code generation to create non-generic classes from your database, or c) use reflection.

Comment: this may be a naive question, but why are you creating objects that appear to mimic the ado.net datatable, and datarow (and presumably datacolumn?)?

Comment: this is a school assignment , i am a student , this is why 
this is a F*^^&*% Data Structure Course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern you can commonly find in the .NET Framework is to define a non-generic base class or interface:

```
public abstract class Field
{
    protected Field() { }

    public abstract BoxedValue { get; set; }

    public abstract Type ValueType { get; }
}

public class Field<T> : Field
{
    private T value; 

    public Field(T value) { this.value = value; }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set { this.value = value;; }
    }

    public override object BoxedValue
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set { this.value = (T)value; }
    }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get { return typeof(T); }
    }
}
```

The Record class exposes a collection of non-generic fields:

```
public class Record
{
    public IEnumerable<Field> Fields { get { ... } }
}
```

If code needs to get the value of fields without boxing, it needs to cast the Field instance to the matching Field<T> first.

*Example:*

```
foreach (Field<int> field in record.Fields.OfType<Field<int>>())
{
    int value = field.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Comment: 10x that set me on the right path there are just 2 things i don't understand , 
(1) : you cant have 2 classes named Field 
(2) : since when does an abstract class contain a Constractor

Comment: 1. You can have two classes named Field if they differ in the number of generic arguments. 2. Abstract classes can have constructors, although they cannot be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use interfaces here

IField ... make a generic class that uses this

Then inherit off this with a

IField interface

now you can have a List  which would actually contain a list of IField

```
interface IField 
{ 
object Data{get;set;}
}

interface IField<T> : IField
{
T TypedObject{get;set;}
}
```

Now you can have a List that has IField object added to it.

EDIT: I dont like to use base classes unless i really have to because that then removes the possibility of using inheritance later. Inheritance is a simple solution but comes with a whole host of caveats imo